# Is there a sunset/sunrise function built into Astropy yet?

Tags: python, coordinates, pyephem, astropy

I have seen a couple of answers referring to PyEphem on here and how that can produce sunset/sunrise times, however it would be more useful to me if I could find a solution using solely Astropy packages. At the moment the closest I have found is the *(get_sun)* function in the **astropy.coordinates** package. Is this sunset/sunrise functionality built into Astropy anywhere yet?

Comment: Short answer: no. [astroplan](https://github.com/astropy/astroplan) is perhaps the closest, but I think that also uses PyEphem under the hood (and PyEphem is being replaced by Skyfield nowadays; same author).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Astroplan](http://astroplan.readthedocs.org) package has an [Observer](http://astroplan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/astroplan.Observer.html) class with a [Observer.sun_rise_time](http://astroplan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/astroplan.Observer.html#astroplan.Observer.sun_rise_time) and a [Observer.sun_set_time](http://astroplan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/astroplan.Observer.html#astroplan.Observer.sun_set_time) method.

Astroplan is an [Astropy affiliated package](http://www.astropy.org/affiliated/index.html).

Whether this functionality is going to be put into the core Astropy package in the future or remain in Astroplan isn't clear. But with `pip install astroplan` or `conda install -c astropy astroplan` you can easily install Astroplan and use this.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to work out the current position of the sun with get_sun, this could be expanded to determine the next sunrise or sunset time is.

I use the following to check if close to sunrise for an automatic closure of my telescope.

```
def almostSunrise():                                                                                
    now = Time(datetime.utcnow(), format='datetime', scale='utc')                                  
    altazframe = AltAz(obstime=now, location=lapalma)                                               
    sunaltaz = get_sun(now).transform_to(altazframe)                                                
    if sunaltaz.alt.value >= -5 and sunaltaz.alt.value <= 5:                                         
        return True                                                                                 
    else:                                                                                           
        return False
```

where lapalma is an `EarthLocation` that I've set up.